# how to deal with page number under pagination bar

Tags: javascript, extjs

[image]

I have a pagination bar which show page number but the problem with it is that till 9th page number it shows the correct result but as soon as i enter 10 then page number shows 0 which is the unit digit of 10,it also jumps to page 10 but cant figure out to show larger number  on that pagination bar.

for pagination i added this

```
tbar : {
        xtype : 'pagingtoolbar',
        displayInfo : true,
        store : 'allinvoices'
    },
    bbar : {
        xtype : 'pagingtoolbar',
        displayInfo : true,
        store : 'allinvoices'
    },

    height : 650,
    width : true,
```

Comment: show me your code

Comment: however i am having servlet where i am handling the page limit for the pagination but that would be a different context .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `dockedItems` instead of `tbar` then the resize will be done automatically. You can also use `dock` option to choose where in the screen you want to have your dockbar fixed.

```
dockedItems: [{
    xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
    dock: 'bottom',
    store: allinvoices
}
```

Comment: please don't just put codes as answers, add some explanation too.